# Method doesn't exist if declared in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

I have a page defined as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/c#">
    public void WriteHello()
    {
        Response.Write("HELLO EVERYBODY");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <% WriteHello(); %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this throws the compilation error of:

> The name 'WriteHello' does not exist in the current context

If I move the C# code to a seperate file, and link to it, it works as expected. But for this I need to keep it in the same file. Can you not call inline methods like this? Or am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `script` tag you have coded is a *client side* script - it will try to execute on the *browser*. The code that tries to use it runs on the *server*.

You need to change the script to be *server side* script:

```
<script runat="server">
```

You can write this as:

```
<%
    public void WriteHello()
    {
        Response.Write("HELLO EVERYBODY");
    }
%>
```

Which is the syntax you used elsewhere already.

Comment: Dammit always something simple! Cheers.

Comment: @anothershrubery - It's only simple when you already know the answer ;)

Comment: True, but should have been able to spot that!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
<script runat=server type="text/c#">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
```

Otherwise your code will not get compiled at runtime